# Run parallel commands in script on Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a python script in which i run two commands using subProcess.
I want these commands to run in parallel. When i run the python script on my machine these commands do run in parallel but when i run the script via Jenkins it runs them one after the other.
How can i run these command in parallel in jenkins?

```
    reg_path = os.environ['PWD']
    command1 = f'python3 {python_script_path} {reg_path} '
    command2 = f'python3 {python_script_path} {reg_path} '

    processes = []

    for i in range(1):
        f = subprocess.Popen(command2, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        p = subprocess.Popen(command1, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        processes.append((p, f))
        p.wait()
        out, err = p.communicate()
        fout, ferr = f.communicate()
        p.kill()
        f.kill()
       
        errMsg = 'other processes are running'
        assert errMsg in str(fout) or errMsg in str(out)
```

Thanks

Comment: The code you posted contains an unpaired `'` (the very first one). Please take care to avoid such distractions and [edit] to provide a proper [mre].

Comment: What's with the `for` loop anyway? You are launching both processes serially inside the loop but only waiting for one of them. Presumably you'd want to loop over your commands, `Popen` each, then wait for either of them to finish, then wait for the other one. Check out the `poll` method, and see the questions about parallel subprocesses on the [`subprocess` tag info page](/tags/subprocess/info)

Comment: Explicitly running Python as a subprocess of itself is weird anyway. Maybe look at `multiprocessing` instead.

Comment: @tripleee Yes the for loop is redundant here you're right. My point is that it works on my machine but I'm assuming that on jenkins machine there isnt a way to run it parallelly

Comment: Your code should run serially in both places because that's how you wrote it. The initial `Popen` will start running first but then you are blocking on `communicate` for each of the processes serially.

Comment: @tripleee so i should just use Popen for both processes?

Comment: Like I wrote, you should perhaps refactor the code to avoid explicit subprocesses.

Answer (score 0):

On Jenkins I would suggest you use the parallel pipeline if possible:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("my python scripts") {
            parallel {
                stage("Script 1") {
                     sh("python3 script1.py ${env.WORKSPACE}")
                }
                stage("Script 2") {
                     sh("python3 script2.py ${env.WORKSPACE}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will run both your `script1.py` and `script2.py` in parallel, without requiring a managing script to handle subprocesses.